# Extend model.save method Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can I take the .save method of certain activeRecord models and add functionality to it?  I would also like to use some of the attributes of the item being saved in that function

Can I do something like?

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.save
        <added stuff for save>
        <including some_other_id_from_this_item>
    end
end
```

or will that break things?  And how do I actually access this_item.the_column_i_need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [ActiveRecords callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to extend the behavior of save.

With the before_save hook you can access data before the record is saved, for example to change case of entered email you can do something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :downcase_email

  def downcase_email
    email.downcase!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use callback **aftet_save** instead. access to any column just by **attribute name** if you read and **self.db_column_name** if you need to change it